# react-native is not creating by using (expo init my-app)

Tags: react-native

after installing the npm install -g expo/cli.. i am trying to use expo init my-app but it was throwing the error  Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from the stack trace, you've got an **ENOGIT** error.

> No git binary found in $PATH.

For some reasons `expo` needs git to initialize the project. And it tries to install `react-native-maps` from the [git repository](https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/2de3f90a139d07bffa46046ff10bece66a9fb60c/packages/expo/package.json#L141) (not from npm).

This means you need to install git on your machine. For Windows, there is a method described [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#_installing_on_windows).

And your warning about the `kleur` is just a warning and you can simply ignore it and it is not your problem.